# How to use multiple audio outputs (of a mac) simultaneously?

Tags: mac, audio, bluetooth, appletv

I have en external USB-audio device, which is great (Steinberg/Yamaha).
And a bluetooth speaker and an Apple TV.

Is it possible to stream audio to ALL this devices simultaneously and synchronously ?

Answer (score 45):

For this you can use the App "Audio MIDI Setup" in /Applications/Utilities.

When you open the app, you will see a list of all audio devices in the list to the left. With the "+" button at the bottom you can create a new **Aggregate Device** or a **Multi-Output Device**.

The devices created there will show up as normal audio devices in the system preferences' "Sound" settings.

The Multi-Output Device seems to be what you are looking for. It will output the audio to all devices enabled in the right part of the window.

The Aggregate Device allows you to join multiple sound cards to simulate one audio device with more output channels (e.g. instead of four separate stereo outputs you would see a single 8 channel output).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For now, I have made only  one test. I tried to create a multiple device with my external USB audio card, the internal speakers of my screen and a bluetooth speaker. Result: the sound is output only from the external sound card. But I do not despair, I will try again very soon and study the problem.

Comment: This is great! Thanks, itspete, it's working very well for me. I am now playing streaming music using the Built-in Output (Yosemite) and AirPlay (Airport -> home theater.) This is something I've wanted to do for some time, but didn't know it was possible. Hooray for apple.stackexchange!

Comment: Hi, this worked for me; I have now attached a subwoofer to my MacBook Pro that uses it's internal speakers for the higher frequencies. However, the system volume control becomes disabled. Any way to remedy?

Comment: I'm seeing the same as @bjornte ; the system volume control becomes disabled. Is there a fix for this? Thank you!

Comment: If I add 'airport express' as an item to 'multi output device', it adds it and I can see it under MUD, but nothing happens, no audio. The airport express otherwise works correctly. Why have apple made this so hard? I just want to stream safari audio out of the imac speakers and the airport express at the same time. This works when doing it from iTunes so why is it nigh impossible from safari?

Comment: It doesn't work if you have two MacBooks and want to hear the audio from both speakers of both macs.

Comment: Thank you!  WFM, M1 Apple Silicon MacBook Air and a bluetooth speaker!  

Now if only there was a way to delay the sound going to the internal speakers so it would be in sync with the bluetooth one!  Ah, well.  (Didn't help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59390/what-is-sound-drift-correction-on-os-x-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: This definitely should work, but on my old Mojave MacBook Air as soon as I try to combine AirPlay with local the AirPlay option goes gray and it only outputs locally. 

I think it used to work years ago.

Comment: OTOH the native iTunes (Mojave) interface has a multiple audio output option and that DOES work. So maybe the Midi feature is not compatible with audio output from iTunes Mojave. Have to do the dual output controls from iTunes. For other apps use Midi feature?

Comment: For folks looking to keep volume control working, [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) is a paid solution that works without sacrificing volume keys on the keyboard.